# Keras, siamese network, how to abstract feature?

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

I'm trying to modify [Keras Siamese Network](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_siamese_graph.py) example to get image feature.

The problem is, how can I get image features? The output of last layer is only a number. What should I do to get the feature before `euclidean_distance`?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to first train the model on the entire dataset and save it.

Load the model back again, now set the output layers to be `processed_a` and `processed_b`

Now call the `model.predict()` function on the entire dataset once again and you'll have the features for each image in the dataset.

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I face the below error!
Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_69:0", shape=(?, 1, 80, 80), dtype=float32) at layer "input_69". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []

Answer (score 1):

To get the embeddings from the [Keras siamese network MNIST](https://keras.io/examples/mnist_siamese/) example after training:

```
model_a = Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=processed_a)
model_a.predict([tr_pairs[:, 0], tr_pairs[:, 1]])
```

Comment: I am getting below error |
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_2:0", shape=(?, 1, 80, 80), dtype=float32) at layer "input_2". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []

Answer (score 0):

I did it as follows ([reference from my github post](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8748)):

My trained siamese model looked like this:
`siamese_model.summary()`

[image]

**Note** that my newly redefined model is basically the same as the one highlighted in yellow

I **then redefined my model which I wanted to use for extracting embeddings** (It should be the same model you defined except now it will not have those multiple inputs like siamese) which looked like this:

`siamese_embeddings_model = build_siamese_model(input_shape)`

`siamese_embeddings_model .summary()`

[image]

Then I just extracted the weights from my trained siamese model and set them into my new model

`embeddings_weights = siamese_model.layers[-3].get_weights()`

`siamese_embeddings_model.set_weights(embeddings_weights )`

Then you can supply the new Image to extract the embeddings from the new model

`vector = siamese.predict(image)`

`len(vector[0])` it will print 150 because of my fine dense layer (which are the output vector)